# Gremlin : AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0. org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.KravyoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 65536

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am using gremlin to fire query on JanusGraph using Java. My Java code is firing g.addV(...) query using Cluster client.submit(query).
cluster = Cluster.build()
.addContactPoint("localhost")
.port(8182)
.serializer(Serializers.GRAPHSON_V3D0)
.maxInProcessPerConnection(32)
.maxSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(32)
.maxContentLength(1000000)
.maxWaitForConnection(10)
.minConnectionPoolSize(5)
.maxConnectionPoolSize(20)
.create();

Getting following Error:
21:23:05.890 WARN  - Response [PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 393, widx: 393, cap: 393)] could not be deserialized by org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.
org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 65536
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.AbstractGryoClassResolver.readClass(AbstractGryoClassResolver.java:148)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:781)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedKryoAdapter.readClassAndObject(ShadedKryoAdapter.java:39)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedKryoAdapter.readClassAndObject(ShadedKryoAdapter.java:24)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoSerializersV3d0$VertexSerializer.read(GryoSerializersV3d0.java:164)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoSerializersV3d0$VertexSerializer.read(GryoSerializersV3d0.java:132)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedSerializerAdapter.read(ShadedSerializerAdapter.java:52)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedKryoAdapter.readClassAndObject(ShadedKryoAdapter.java:39)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedKryoAdapter.readClassAndObject(ShadedKryoAdapter.java:24)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.ResponseMessageGryoSerializer.read(ResponseMessageGryoSerializer.java:56)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.ResponseMessageGryoSerializer.read(ResponseMessageGryoSerializer.java:34)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedSerializerAdapter.read(ShadedSerializerAdapter.java:52)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:686)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.deserializeResponse(AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.java:157)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.decode(WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.java:47)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.decode(WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.java:35)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.Utf8FrameValidator.channelRead(Utf8FrameValidator.java:82)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
21:23:05.894 ERROR - Could not process the response
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 65536
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:98)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.Utf8FrameValidator.channelRead(Utf8FrameValidator.java:82)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 65536
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.deserializeResponse(AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.java:161)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.decode(WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.java:47)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.decode(WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.java:35)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 65536
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.AbstractGryoClassResolver.readClass(AbstractGryoClassResolver.java:148)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:781)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedKryoAdapter.readClassAndObject(ShadedKryoAdapter.java:39)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedKryoAdapter.readClassAndObject(ShadedKryoAdapter.java:24)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoSerializersV3d0$VertexSerializer.read(GryoSerializersV3d0.java:164)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoSerializersV3d0$VertexSerializer.read(GryoSerializersV3d0.java:132)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedSerializerAdapter.read(ShadedSerializerAdapter.java:52)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedKryoAdapter.readClassAndObject(ShadedKryoAdapter.java:39)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedKryoAdapter.readClassAndObject(ShadedKryoAdapter.java:24)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.ResponseMessageGryoSerializer.read(ResponseMessageGryoSerializer.java:56)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.ResponseMessageGryoSerializer.read(ResponseMessageGryoSerializer.java:34)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.shaded.ShadedSerializerAdapter.read(ShadedSerializerAdapter.java:52)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:686)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.deserializeResponse(AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.java:157)
... 36 common frames omitted
21:23:06.436 INFO  - Checking for pending messages to complete before close on org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Connection$CheckForPending@147b072d
21:23:06.647 INFO  - Checking for pending messages to complete before close on org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Connection$CheckForPending@1a6846d2

But i can see that Vertex is getting addedd in my Janus. but code is returning error.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Variations of this question have come up before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60638744/connecting-janusgraph-using-gremlin-and-java-gives-serialization-exception-enco) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53202745/janusgraph-0-3-0-tinkerpop-3-3-3-java-serialization-error-after-adding-edge-us) on StackOverflow and [TINKERPOP-2372](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2372)), but generally speaking it means that there is a serializer on the server that is no available on the client (or the other way around potentially though that is less common). In your case, you probably just need to add the `JanusGraphIoRegistry` to your driver configuration as shown in those links but for convenience and to directly answer your version of the question I'll use your `Cluster` builder setup:

```
GryoMapper mapper = GryoMapper.build().addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.INSTANCE).create();
Cluster cluster = Cluster.build().
                          addContactPoint("localhost").port(8182).
                          serializer(new GryoMessageSerializerV1d0(mapper)).
                          maxInProcessPerConnection(32).
                          maxSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(32).
                          maxContentLength(1000000).
                          maxWaitForConnection(10).
                          minConnectionPoolSize(5).
                          maxConnectionPoolSize(20).create();
```

I do find it odd that you are getting Gryo based errors but are using a GraphSON serializer in your code snippet. I'm assume that perhaps that's just a bad copy/paste situation. Note that you may wish to review the JanusGraph documentation that goes over this aspect of configuring the driver at: [7.4.2.1. Connecting to JanusGraph via Gremlin Server](https://old-docs.janusgraph.org/0.2.0/server.html#gremlin-server-with-janusgraph)